# EF does not accept my primary key in its SQL Statement

Tags: entity-framework

I have create a table with this schema :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
[KeyID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[OtherID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[Info] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TX_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [KeyID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have created this POCO Class :

```
public partial class A
{
    public A()
    {
    }

    public System.Guid KeyID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> OtherID{ get; set; }
    public string Info{ get; set; }
}
```

When I try to insert a new line in my table with Entity Framework :

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAdd( )
{
A a = new A( );
Guid myKey = Guid.Parse("9B3CA1AC-279F-48CE-B693-D5329FF3AD14");

a.OtherID = myKey;
a.KeyID = myKey;
a.Info = "Test";

using( var database = new myConnection( ) )
{
    database.A.Add( a );
    database.SaveChangesAsync( ).Wait( );
}    
}
```

It produces this SQL command :

```
DECLARE @generated_keys table([A] uniqueidentifier)
INSERT [dbo].[A]([OtherID], [Info])
OUTPUT inserted.[KeyID] INTO @generated_keys
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT t.[KeyID]
FROM @generated_keys AS g JOIN [dbo].[A] AS t ON g.[KeyID] = t.[KeyID]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
```

Then it generates this error :

> Can not insert the value NULL into column 'KeyID', table 'A. This column does not accept NULL values. INSERT failed.

It seems it doesn't take into account the primary key ID specified and it seems to believe that the primary key is auto incremented.

But this SQL statement works fine in SQL Server :

```
INSERT INTO A (KeyID, OtheriD, Info) 
VALUES('9B3CA1AC-279F-48CE-B693-D5329FF3AD14', '9B3CA1AC-279F-48CE-B693-D5329FF3AD14', 'test')
```

Do you know what's wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your Entity Framework configuration is set up for database-generated primary key columns, that's why you also see in the SQL how EF attempts to retrieve the new `KeyID` value even though it hasn't set it. Your primary key column isn't database-generated, so this can never work.

If you let EF generate your database for you, you would have got a matching one. If you create your database manually, it has to match what EF thinks it should be, or you get errors like this.

You can chance your model to not treat the key column as database-generated with the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute, specifying `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`.

Comment: I have the same error when I use : [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.None )] or modelBuilder.Entity<A>( ).Property( v => v.KeyID ).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption( DatabaseGeneratedOption.None );

Comment: @christophe Can you try letting EF generate the database for you, and check whether it sets a default constraint for your key column? If it does, then something is causing your `DatabaseGenerated` attribute to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

I used EF to build my Database : 


IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[A]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[A];
GO

-- Creating table 'A'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A] (
    [KeyID] uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL,
    [OtherID] uniqueidentifier  NULL,
    [Info] nvarchar(50)  NOT NULL,
);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [KeyID] in table 'A'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[A]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_A]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([KeyID] ASC);
GO


It doesn't work ...

Comment: @christophe To clarify, is that what you get with your current model, or what you previously got and are now still using?

Comment: I made no change since last time. My database has been created by my EDMX file and I have used the templates (*.tt) automatically created by EF. As you have recommanded, I have added the attribute [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.None )]. It doesn't work ... I'm wondering if it is possible, with EF, to have a entity key which will would be filled only at runtime ? This problem is specific to EF because when I use a T-SQL command, I have no error.

Comment: @christophe Wait... Your earlier comment used `modelBuilder`, but now you've got an EDMX file? You have to use one or the other, it cannot be both. If you're using an EDMX file, it needs to be set from that, where it is called `StoreGeneratedPattern`.

Comment: It is very difficult to explain my problem in 4 lines without carriage returns ;(. First, I decided to use a EDMX file because I prefer have a visual representation of my work for designing and especially for relationships between tables. Second, I created the SQL file with the option "generate database from model". Third, I generated all C# classes with the *.TT files automatically generated. Finally, I have excluded the EDMX file from my project.That's all for EDMX ! From now, I consider that I am in the "Model First" concept of EF.

Comment: @christophe Okay, but that still means your database is generated from the EDMX file, not from your Code First model, and there are some differences between them. When I asked to try to let EF generate the database for you, it should be from the same model you're using now.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
public void TestAdd( )
{
   A a = new A( );
   Guid myKey = Guid.NewGuid();//use this

   a.OtherID = myKey;
   a.KeyID = myKey;
   a.Info = "Test";

   using( var database = new myConnection( ) )
   {
      database.A.Add( a );
      database.SaveChangesAsync( ).Wait( );
   }    
 }
```

Comment: Guid.Parse("9B3CA1AC-279F-48CE-B693-D5329FF3AD14") produce a valid Guid... So, your example generates the same error